# Grails Liquibase plugin and Taggable plugin

Tags: grails, liquibase

Perhaps this is a shot in the dark but I am attempting to use the Grails Liquibase plugin and it appears as though there is a compatibility issue with the Taggable plugin. The Taggable plugin works by implementing `Taggable` on the domain classes which you want to be taggable.

When I try to run the Liquibase command `grails generate-changelog` I get the following exception on the classes implementing `Taggable`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsControllerClass
```

If I remove `implements Taggable` this error goes away.

I am thinking this has something to do with the class loader; perhaps `Taggable` isn't getting loaded?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For database migrations there's now a ['official' plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-database-migration/).